# How to Check Partial View Render time Load in jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partial view which I am rendering using jQuery dialog.
I want to check Partial view Render time in Minutes, Seconds and Milliseconds.
Please help me any one how to check Render time.

Answer (score 1):

```
@{ 
     var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew(); 
    Trace.WriteLine("View Index - rendering..."); 
}     

<!-- standard view rendering goes here(in your case partial view content) -->


@{ 
    stopwatch.Stop(); 
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("View Index - rendered: {0} ms", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds)); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.